# Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, mvc

Yo se que cuando intento eliminar una llave primaria que se esta usando en otra tabla, genera un error PERO YO QUIERO PODER ATRAPAR ESE ERROR para mostrar un mensaje al usuario diciendo que no puede eliminar dicho elemento porque se esta usando en otra parte, ya que actualmente me sale un error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`genesis`.`producto`, CONSTRAINT `producto_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`codigoMedida`) REFERENCES `unidades_medida` (`codigo`)) in C:\xampp\htdocs\apicola\models\ActiveRecord.php:261 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\apicola\models\ActiveRecord.php(261): mysqli->query('DELETE FROM uni...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\apicola\controllers\MedidaController.php(61): Model\ActiveRecord->eliminarLlaveExcepciones('codigo', '1') #2 [internal function]: Controllers\MedidaController::eliminarMedida(Object(MVC\Router)) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\apicola\Router.php(51): call_user_func(Array, Object(MVC\Router)) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\apicola\public\index.php(67): MVC\Router->comprobarRutas() #5 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\apicola\models\ActiveRecord.php on line 261
```

Pero yo ya se que no se puede , este es mi codigo

```
public function eliminarLlaveExcepciones($llave,$valor) {
        $resultado=null;
        try {
            $query = "DELETE FROM " . static::$tabla . " WHERE $llave = $valor LIMIT 1";
            // debuguear($query);
            $resultado = self::$db->query($query);
            // debuguear($query);

            if ($resultado === false) {
                $errorInfo = self::$db->errorInfo();
                // Verifica si el código de error es '23000' (violación de integridad referencial)
                if ($errorInfo[1] == '23000') {
                    echo "Error: No se puede eliminar la llave primaria porque está siendo referenciada en otro lugar.";
                } else {
                    echo "Error: " . $errorInfo[2]; // Otro tipo de error
                }
            } else {
                // Resto de tu código después de la eliminación exitosa
                echo "Llave primaria eliminada exitosamente";
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Otras excepciones generales (no relacionadas con la base de datos)
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $resultado;
    }
```

Comment: la unica forma de atrapar los fatal error es que implementes un php.ini o htaccess que llame a un manejador de errores con: `php_value auto_prepend_file "/var/www/html/manejador-error.php"`

Comment: y el reto no finaliza aqui... si no que tienes despues que implementar: ShutdownHandler, ErrorHandler y ExceptionHandler, para manipular y capturar correctamente cualquier error de php ... yo tengo algo medianamente funcional haca: https://github.com/arcanisgk/PHP-Development-Tools pero no esta terminado

Comment: es un kit de desarrollo para ayudar a mejorar el output de errores y datos para debuggear

Comment: elotro inconveniente es que no es correcto mostrar esos errores a usuarios finales, lo correcto es capturar el error y colocarlo en un logo con un timestamp y mostrarle el time stamp al usuario, como numero de seguimiento para si hay algo que investigar o reclamar ...

Comment: por otro lado te invito a que hagas el [tour]